# Quartz.NET trigger states - what states require administrator attention?

Tags: triggers, quartz.net

I'm using Quartz.NET in an application I am creating, and also a backup application that will detect when Quartz is 'not working right' - this can be the scheduler being down, or, in this case, triggers in specific states where they will never be executed.

But, which states would I need to check for? i.e, which states would require administrator attention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be any triggers stuck in 'Blocked' mostly